# Laravel Pluck and combine two fields to generate a select menu

Tags: php, laravel, pluck

Let's say I have the following fields in my database for a user, `id`, `first_name` and `last_name`. I want to generate a select menu, something like below:

```
<select>
    <option value="id">first_name + last_name</option>
</select>
```

I know I can use `pluck` to get an array with `id` as the key and one more field as the value:

```
User::pluck('first_name', 'id')->all();
```

And this would produce:

```
array:4 [▼
  1 => "John"
  2 => "Linda"
  3 => "Jane"
  4 => "Carl"
]
```

Is there an easy way using eloquent to get the `first_name` AND the `last_name` so I can get the following:

```
array:4 [▼
  1 => "John Doe"
  2 => "Linda Smith"
  3 => "Jane Doe"
  4 => "Carl Johnson"
]
```

The `first_name` and `last_name` are examples to explain my question, I need to combine two other fields instead which cannot be 'merged' into one field.

Comment: Can you not map over the collection and transform it however you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is to append the model attribute on fly get full name.

**In Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
   public $appends = [ 'full_name' ];

   public function getFullNameAttribute()
   {
      return $this->first_name .' '. $this->last_name;
   }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
User::pluck('full_name', 'id')->all();
```

If you are using Laravel latest version, follow this as well https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Ah yes, with an accessor, cool and I should have though of that!